# Can't get columns to fit grid width

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, grid-system

I'm using Semantic UI and can't properly set the grids. According to the docs, Semantic UI uses 16 columns and I'm trying to have a column with width of `three` on the left side and next to it a column with the width of `thirteen`. This is how it looks (pic is cropped):

[image]

I have used Bootstrap for a long time and now trying to use Semantic UI. What am I missing? [Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/7lyLGOBtXJpLJpaMVOMf/)

```
<header>
    <div class="mobile hidden">
        <div class="ui container">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="eight column">
                    <div class="ui secondary menu">
                        <a class="active item">
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <a class="item">
                            Messages
                        </a>
                        <a class="item">
                            Friends
                        </a>
                        <div class="right menu">
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="ui icon input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                                    <i class="search link icon"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="ui item">
                                Logout
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="clearing"></div>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="mobile hidden">
        <div class="ui grid row">
            <aside class="three column red">

            </aside>
            <section class="thirteen column olive">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab doloremque illum quas? Dolore dolorem dolorum ipsum? Commodi error excepturi laboriosam magnam nobis odio suscipit unde! Alias atque dicta reiciendis sapiente!
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to share a working example (maybe on plnkr or any other website of your choice)? It will help to understand

Comment: @S4beR https://embed.plnkr.co/7lyLGOBtXJpLJpaMVOMf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing two additional classes `wide` and  `field` in your `HTML` element. change that like below

```
<aside class="three wide field column red"></aside>
<section class="thirteen wide field column olive">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab doloremque illum quas? Dolore dolorem dolorum ipsum? Commodi error excepturi laboriosam magnam nobis odio suscipit unde! Alias atque dicta reiciendis sapiente!
</section>
```

Comment: css is declared like that in https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css. it looks for `.three.wide.field` to apply `width`. on it's own `.wide.field` doesn't specify any css property.